# Vue.js range slider, set v-model and get changes

Tags: forms, vue.js, slider, rangeslider

I am putting a slider on my web form for users to enter how much they would like to rate a certain thing.

[image]

I am using Vue.js and I am not sure how to set up a v-model on this and how to get user's entered value.

```
<div v-else class="form-group">
    <form action="">
        <label for="formControlRange">Please drag the slider to decide how much you want to rate between 1 and 10</label>
        <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange">
    </form>
<div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to add the v-model attribute to your range input:

```
<input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange" v-model="value">
```

And define `value` (however you want to name it) in your component.

```
...
data: {
  value: 50 //initial value
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q0Lmv196/

Comment: awesome, can you help me to display the numbers on the slider for a user?

Comment: Apparently there is a possibility to add tickmarks/labels to a range slider. But currently, no browser supports this feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Adding_hash_marks_and_labels Probably you have to search for a alternative (third party component - e.g. this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-slider)

Comment: but i don't get to show at least `  <h1>
    {{value}}
    </h1>`  on the display.

Comment: Ah okay, I misunderstood that

Comment: No, that was still useful because I was hoping I could add some nicer UI on the slider, too.

Comment: @user9307178 You can use v-range-slider from Vuetify